# Circle Ci- Run rspec tests parallely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, continuous-integration, circleci

I added an additional container in circle ci and tried to run tests parallaly.

This is my `circle.yml` file.

```
machine:
  ruby:
    version: 2.3.0
database:
  post:
    - cp config/sunspot.ci.yml config/sunspot.yml
    - bundle exec sunspot-solr start -p 8981
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install solr-tomcat

test:
  override:
    - rvm use 2.3.0 && bundle exec rspec --color --format progress:
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
        parallel: true
        files:
          - "spec/**/*_spec.rb"
```

but tests don't seem to be running in parallel.
What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: I have same issue .. I ended up with remuving everything under test section and it somehow automagically worked ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason removing `rvm use 2.3.0` from test section fixed my problem.

```
machine:
  ruby:
    version: 2.3.0
database:
  # After default database task finished
  post:
    # Circle CI already replace our original sunspot.yml, replace it with backup copy `config/sunspot.yml.ci`
    - cp config/sunspot.ci.yml config/sunspot.yml
    - bundle exec sunspot-solr start -p 8981
dependencies:
  pre:
    - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -y install solr-tomcat

test:
  override:
    - bundle exec rspec --tag ~@flaky --color --profile 20 --format progress:
        timeout: 240
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: test
        parallel: true
        files:
          - my files here
```